# undefined flutter create --ios-language objc --android-language java

Tags: flutter, dart, undefined

installed flutter and flutter doctor working perfect but when i run flutter: new project in vscode it showing BELOW ERROR:

```
[undefined] flutter create --ios-language objc --android-language java .
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Creating project ....
.gitignore (created)

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: aa59e1a8c31996c2)
Crash report written to C:\Users\mr\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_07.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I am new to StackOverflow. Can you explain